# Doctrine 2, serialization returning proxy class

Tags: doctrine-orm, silex

I'm using Silex and Doctrine to create an API, which makes use of Doctrine Associations. I'm using JMSSerializer to serialize entities.

All entities are returned as nice JSON objects except one, which has a ManyToOne association.

I find when this particular entity is serialized, it is actually the serialized Proxy class, including properties such as:

```
"__initializer__": null,
"__cloner__": null,
"__isInitialized__": true,
```

Why am I getting the proxy class in this case instead of the Entity? I've tried calling methods on the Objects in the application before serialization in an attempt to load the complete Entities, but I always seem to get the Proxy class.

Comment: Once a proxy, always a proxy.  You need to setup a query and select the associated objects so they won't be lazy loaded.

Comment: @Cerad, thanks for your response, I will try this. It seems odd though that while I can simply refer to all other Entities in the application without direct queries, this single case requires some special handling.

Comment: It looks like JMSSerializer is designed to take proxies into account. I don't see any issues in github for this. Check to make sure you're using the latest version. If you are, you should submit an issue to github. https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/issues

Answer (score 0):

My interim solution was to change the ManyToOne association to a ManyToMany and implement a ManyToOne constraint in the Model.

This is not elegant but it does seem to prevent the ORM from providing a proxy class and provide useful entities for both sides of the association when one is fetched.